# How do I convert an ObjectURL to a DB Insertable BLOB

Tags: javascript

Sending PHP the retval of the Object URL created from an image (`blob:http://...`) and using PHP's `base64_encode()` along side with `file_get_contents()` returns an error claiming that there is no stream or file.

Comment: blob URIs point to data in memory or user's disk. Your PHP script can't do anything with it, because the data isn't accessible to your server. You need to send the data that is pointed by this URI instead of sending the URI itself. Not knowing how you did generate the URI in the first place we can't really help you on how to send the correct data.

Comment: It's just a local blob created with `URL.createObjectURL()`. Is there any way I can get the actual image rather than just the URI?

Comment: Send the same Blob that you passed to createObjectURL(blob).

Answer (score 0):

How about send url of image. then use file_get_contents('http://...') to get the image file content.

For example, your image url is http://example.com/test.jpg

JS

```
// if image is a link
axiso.post(url, {image: "http://example.com/test.jpg"})

// if image is file select from local, upload file
let data = new FormaData();
formData.append("image", this.files[0]);
axiso.post(url, data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```

PHP

```
// get file content from image link
file_get_contents('http://example.com/test.jpg')

// get content from upload file
$name= "image";
file_get_contents($_FILES[$name]);
```

Comment: It's based on an input file type change event. The image uploaded isn't stored anywhere, we just change the source of the HTML img element to the file blob.

:: `onchange="document.getElementById('character-mugshot').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"`

Comment: @Nathan then you can just upload files[0] with Content-Type=multipart/form-data.